# The TAK function

Tags: code-golf, math, recursion

The [TAK function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TAKFunction.html) is defined as follows for integers \$x\$, \$y\$, \$z\$:

$$
t(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
y, & \text{if $x \le y$} \\
t(t(x-1,y,z), t(y-1,z,x), t(z-1,x,y)), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Since it can be proved that it always terminates and evaluates to the simple function below,

$$
t(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
y, & \text{if $x \le y$} \\
z, & \text{if $x > y$ and $y \le z$} \\
x, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

your job is not to just implement the function, but **count the number of calls to \$t\$** when initially called with the given values of \$x\$, \$y\$, and \$z\$. (As per the standard rules, you don't need to implement \$t\$ if there is a formula for this value.)

You may assume that the three input values are nonnegative integers.

Note that the task is slightly different from the definition of the function \$T\$ (the number of "otherwise" branches taken) on the Mathworld page.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
(x, y, z) -> output

(0, 0, 1) -> 1
(1, 0, 2) -> 5
(2, 0, 3) -> 17
(3, 0, 4) -> 57
(4, 0, 5) -> 213
(5, 0, 6) -> 893

(1, 0, 0) -> 5
(2, 0, 0) -> 9
(2, 1, 0) -> 9
(3, 0, 0) -> 13
(3, 1, 0) -> 29
(3, 2, 0) -> 17
(4, 0, 0) -> 17
(4, 1, 0) -> 89
(4, 2, 0) -> 53
(4, 3, 0) -> 57
(5, 0, 0) -> 21
(5, 1, 0) -> 305
(5, 2, 0) -> 149
(5, 3, 0) -> 209
(5, 4, 0) -> 213
```

[Python implementation](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVExDsIwDNz7ittohCvBghCi_CVAA5UqF4VUavoVFhZ4DOID_Ia0CW0FC57sy53Pdi73kzXHkq_XW2VUsnw995mCimuCJTRiFcHFThbFGSlmXdUyzBejDS65KB3V03vYi6cp5j2UK9RYp7Ar6MxUmmH7twCY2Fkkc7LUCHKVdXlDdZc3Lq_JCtGJhlGikb5zDTs9VKnByBla8iGLF2HooHOLMWFG4Kkf8aRzNnHfljBJNhMaXUVEkee4pO0tf3u38HaA5ehOg60kbClc9T9jv9Hnt94) was used to generate the test cases.

Comment: So far I've noticed that (using this question's definition of T rather than that of the linked article) `T(x+1,y+1,z+1)=T(x,y,z)` and also `T(x,y,z)=T(y,z,x)` if `x>y` and `y>>z`, but I haven't been able to come up with anything more general.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

**Using a single recursive function**

Expects `(x, y, z)`.

```javascript
f=(x,y,z,w)=>x>(r=y)?f(x-1,y,z)+f(y-1,z,x,w=r)+f(z-1,x,y,z=r)-~f(w,z,r):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJNboMwEIX3nGLUDbZiIoyhDYlMVj0FYoFS6I9QqCBtgKo9QaVuumzv0fPkAj0CHWzSOGmlkeX5PO/N2PJd@pjWq@r2fuOsy6us73NJGtayjm2pjJqIVLKly5w0Dh8oneSkxW3HGraV1ZB2mCoFps5LTrZ4WNE57xexBRCDy4bgGACQMMW4Yh6D4MA8xQTWXfwyoZiPdQfmKxagnIs9CxQ7ZzALxXEP958eGOER46dM7OuwhcHGsUOTaUt@Ot8fprWz0GRaGwiT6dbGfYO9n8dNpv2EGxhsnMUPDab9PNdk/uiHb2Ul1jQvq8t0dUNIDA2DlkHHoHzYQEJBRvAERbaBKqtBAv4DXUAXsCrXdVlk06K8JvGIE5jAGTgRLhMlGdJhT5ReKtsl2N9fb7uPd1xtmIO9@3y1KTo@0/4H)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                     // f is a recursive function taking:
  x, y, z,                //   (x, y, z) = input integers
  w                       //   w = local variable
) =>                      //
x > (r = y) ?             // save y in the global r; if x is greater than y:
  f(x - 1, y, z) +        //   process the 1st recursive call
  f(y - 1, z, x, w = r) + //   save r in w and process the 2nd recursive call
  f(z - 1, x, y, z = r) - //   save r in z and process the 3rd recursive call
  ~f(w, z, r)             //   last recursive call, using the previous results
                          //   add all returned values together, and add 1
:                         // else:
  1                       //   stop and return 1
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

**Using a wrapper function**

Expects `[x, y, z]`.

Simply does exactly what is said on the tin.

```javascript
a=>(r=0,(t=(x,y,z)=>++r&&x>y?t(t(x-1,y,z),t(y-1,z,x),t(z-1,x,y)):y)(...a),r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBdToNAEAfw955i4kPZDVvCsqClzdInT0F4IC31I00xsBrAeAMTX3zUe3ieXsAj4LCA3VaTDRl@mfnPwn36lJbr4u5Bzfb5Jmu3sk1lRArpMqIkqVjNGioj2y6m0yqqV4ooUs24ZqZIjWXDqq5ssMR2Shc1JY7jpJQVtF3GE4AYXNYdjgcAEqaNa/MYBEfztAnsu/o1oc3HvqP52gIc52K0QNslg3koTne4/@zAE54YPzcx9uEKw4Zrh6b1kfz8fn@sn52HpvWzgTCtX218bzDmedy0Pk@4gWHDXfzQsD7Pc03zhzz8V5Nk4mzz4jpd3xISQ8WgZtAwyB8VJBRkBM@wyxQUWQkStiQeOhK6hHW@L/Nd5uzym6ODDRcwi/Bh66HutauJTpA6eAXW99fb4eMdnxYswDp8vloUE19o@wM)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (22?) 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṙJ_JỊ$ṙ-Ñ€Ñ
‘ɼṛṖṪÇ}ṢƑ?
Çṛ®
```

A full program that accepts a list of three non-negative integers, `[x, y, z]`, and prints the call count. (Or 22 bytes as a monadic Link that accepts the same and accumulates in the register (?) - remove the last line.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUgAt/9qZWxsef//4bmZSl9K4buKJOG5mS3DkeKCrMORCuKAmMm84bmb4bmW4bmqw4d94bmixpE/CsOH4bmbwq7///9bNSwgMywgMF0)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzple8V4Pd3epAFm6hyc@alpzeCLXo4YZJ/c83Dn74c5pD3euOtxe@3DnomMT7bkOtwMFD60D6mo7tPLE@sPtOg5HJz3cOSPrUcMcBVs7hUcNczUj//@PjjbQUQAiw1gdhWhDMNMIxDQCM41BTGMw0wTENAEzTUFMUzDTDKHNAKENxjSEMo0RosYookZQpglCgQlCgQmKAmMo0xSh1hSh1hSh1hRFLcjo2FgA).

#### How?

There's probably a clever way to produce the count, but this implements the description from the question.

```
ṙJ_JỊ$ṙ-Ñ€Ñ - Link 1: [x, y, z]
 J          - indices {[x, y, z]} -> [1, 2, 3]
ṙ           - {[x, y, z]} rotate left by -> [[y, z, x], [z, x, y], [x, y, z]]
     $      - last two links as a monad - f([x, y, z]):
   J        -   indices {[x, y, z]} -> [1, 2, 3]
    Ị       -   insignificant?      -> [1, 0, 0]
  _         - subtract     -> [[y-1, z, x], [z-1, x, y], [x-1, y, z]]
      ṙ-    - rotate right -> [[x-1, y, z], [y-1, z, x], [z-1, x, y]]
        Ñ€  - call Link 2 for each
          Ñ - call link 2
           - 

‘ɼṛṖṪÇ}ṢƑ? - Link 2, t: [x, y, z]
 ɼ         - apply to the register and yield:
‘          -   increment
   Ṗ       - pop {[x, y, z]} -> [x, y]
  ṛ        - right argument -> [x,y]
         ? - if...
        Ƒ  - ...condition: is {[x, y]} invariant under?:
       Ṣ   -                 sort
    Ṫ      - ...then: tail -> y
     Ç}    - ...else: call Link 1 as a monad - f(x, y, z)

Çṛ® - Main Link: [x, y, z]
Ç   - call Link 2 as a monad - t(x, y, z)
  ® - recall from the register -> count
 ṛ  - right argument -> count
```

Comment: `Ñ` calls link 2 from link 1, doesn't it?

Comment: Corrected, thanks!

Comment: I don’t think the 22 is valid. It seems akin to storing the result in a variable, and also the monadic link is not reusable since it doesn’t initialise the register. Overall good solution though

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mfeature+signatures -ap`, 83 bytes

```perl
sub f($x,$y,$z){++$;;$y<$x?f(f($x-1,$y,$z),f($y-1,$z,$x),f($z-1,$x,$y)):$y}f@F;$_=$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhTUOlQkelUkelSrNaW1vF2lql0kalwj5NAyShawiV0gHyKkG8Kh2VCjCvCsQD6dTUtFKprE1zcLNWibdV@f/fSMFAwfhffkFJZn5e8X9d37TUxJLSolTt4sz0PDALKFiQCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 103 bytes

```
def t(x,y,z):t.c+=1;return t(t(x-1,y,z),t(y-1,z,x),t(z-1,x,y))if x>y else y
t.c=0
t(*input())
print t.c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY9BTsQwDEX3OYXVzSSMi6YsECrq3CVt06HS4FbBlZpehU03o5G4EUtugttUIARk46__Yz_79doHfurobn6rutpBAUmSXAZu0of3U-0aYD1iwMnkfFvti-zROx48iS1Bmq0Rsg4iJxwXOYmUFmPaBsZjAHd-cRCUtBcHxfqmpX5gbYzqfUsM4m-4DyEr1XQeCFoCb-nk9L3JFchbu2S7s30ua5uDJoQDAu0zs-Zx2DYbYZced7gGbnQVLKepCIwE-5uw2OW3bTf7T7hFKIVvvn78i_-xQjx0nmP9BA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 116 bytes

```
≔⦃⦄θ⊞υＥ³ＮＦυ«≔Ｉ⪫()⪫ι,ηＦ¬§θη¿‹§ι¹§ι⁰«≔ＥιＥι⁻§ι⁺μξ¬ξζ⊞ζＥζ§λ∨¬‹§λ¹§λ⁰⊗¬‹§λ²§λ¹≔Ｅζ§θＩ⪫()⪫λ,ε¿⬤ελ§≔θη⊕ΣεＦ⊞Ｏζι⊞υλ»§≔θη¹»Ｉ§θη
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJNT8JAEE280V8x6Wk3WRKKFxNORC8YBYxH46GURTaZbmE_DIHwS7xw0Ohv8te40y1KDb10tjNv3tv3-vZVLHNTVDkeDh_eLbpX3xcPQ2vVi2a7vYA1HyRTb5fMC7jPV-xSwEivvBv7ciYN4zz0F5UB5jnskk6DvM6tY7eV0ixlPBVQl0pAKtKAELAMqE4NG1eODd1Iz-WGranBOagFsDtp7W8jILOAOjn2aC7wHQlJmooK6aW0b6GnGM6lgA2RE2UoqNySjk59v21Eb_9oUMDE1AJbYrAtBqMYATeVn6GcnwX024CMN8-gfYMT8uDFWRPxaCJRynoB2TVEZFIABlfivlNPKbLCyFJqF_Q9-pLJhluilVDnQB5MVtLkrjKkQ4VNx9yRZvdJnD63PgsD-2RqlHYx-n-JDt7trLDN__X5lHZfMX3-yKAH_fjtBw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Charcoal isn't really suited for this.

```
≔⦃⦄θ
```

Start with an empty dictionary which will hold `T(x, y, z)` for each required tuple.

```
⊞υＥ³Ｎ
```

Start with the input tuple.

```
Ｆυ«
```

Loop over the required tuples as they are found.

```
≔Ｉ⪫()⪫ι,η
```

Convert the tuples from a list to a Python tuple so that they can be used as a dictionary key.

```
Ｆ¬§θη
```

Test to see whether this tuple's `T` value is already known.

```
¿‹§ι¹§ι⁰«
```

Test to see whether this is a trivial tuple.

```
≔ＥιＥι⁻§ι⁺μξ¬ξζ
```

Generate the dependent tuples, `(x-1, y, z)`, `(y-1, z, x)` and `(z-1, x, y)`.

```
⊞ζＥζ§λ∨¬‹§λ¹§λ⁰⊗¬‹§λ²§λ¹
```

Also generate the fourth tuple by calculating `t` for each of these tuples nonrecursively.

```
≔Ｅζ§θＩ⪫()⪫λ,ε
```

Get any `T` values we have for these tuples already.

```
¿⬤ελ
```

If all of these tuples already have `T` values, then...

```
§≔θη⊕Σε
```

... take the sum and set this as the `T` value for the required tuple.

```
Ｆ⊞Ｏζι⊞υλ
```

Otherwise push all of the tuples to the list for reprocessing because it's simpler that way.

```
»§≔θη¹
```

If this is a trivial tuple then just set its `T` value to `1`.

```
»Ｉ§θη
```

Output the `T` value of the input tuple.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"¼Â¦`@iÅsë2Ý._εć<š®.V}®.V"©.V¾
```

Input as a triplet \$[x,y,z]\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f6dCew02HliU4ZB5uLT682ujwXL34c1uPtNscXXhonV5YLYhQOrRSL@zQvv//ow11DHSMYv/r6ubl6@YkVlUCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/pUN7DjcdWpbgkHm4tfjwaqPDc/Xiz2090m5zdOGhdXphtSBC6dBKvbBD@/7r6B3a@j862kDHQMcwVifaEEgbAWkjIG0MpI2BtAmQNgHSpkDaFEibQdUZQNVBaEMwbQzlG8P5RmDaBCpuAhU3gYsbg2lTqLwpVN4UKm8KlweaEBv7X1c3L183J7GqEgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
"..."        # Push the recursive string explained below
     ©       # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
      .V     # Pop and evaluate it as 05AB1E code
        ¾    # Push counter variable `¾`
             # (which is output implicitly as result)

¼            # Increase the counter variable `¾` by 1 (starts at 0 by default)
Â            # Bifurcate the current triplet; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
             # (which will use the implicit input-triplet in the first iteration)
 ¦           # Remove the first item of the reversed triplet (the z)
  `          # Pop and push y and x separated to the stack
   @i        # Pop both, and if x>=y:
     Ås      #  Pop the triplet, and push its middle: y
    ë        # Else:
     2Ý      #  Push list [0,1,2]
       ._    #  Rotate the triplet that many times towards the left: [[x,y,z],[y,z,x],[z,x,y]]
     ε       #  Map over each rotated triplet:
      ć      #   Extract its head; push remainder-pair and first item separately
       <     #   Decrease this first item by 1
        š    #   Prepend it back to the pair
         ®.V #   Do a recursive call by evaluating string `®`
     }®.V    #  After the map: do a recursive call on the resulting triplet as well
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), 82 bytes

```
func t(x,y,z){$0=++c;return x>y?t(t(x-1,y,z),t(y-1,z,x),t(z-1,x,y)):y}t($1,$2,$3)1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JY5BCoMwEEX3OUUWWSQYIRNtKS22d-gNitRNwYVEaiyepBtBeihv05_J5vEy_8-Q7_Z4v9b1N4auPO33buxbGfRko53NR7mmKNrL8Azj0MvpGm9BIyyJYxt0hM52SjpDsWbMOS5BK7LKW1UZype3tnHZ1n1x0kkSBHrhwUpUYC1q8CAO4JFTx2kiXtxJzI6E-4nEzBO0-EIiMT0zz7GRf_EH)