# The TAK function (easy mode)

Tags: code-golf, math

The [TAK function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TAKFunction.html) is defined as follows for integers \$x\$, \$y\$, \$z\$:

$$
t(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
y, & \text{if $x \le y$} \\
t(t(x-1,y,z), t(y-1,z,x), t(z-1,x,y)), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

It can be proved that it always terminates and evaluates to the simple function below:

$$
t(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
y, & \text{if $x \le y$} \\
z, & \text{if $x > y$ and $y \le z$} \\
x, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Your job is to implement the function. (As per the standard rules, it is OK to implement the simplified version, or anything else that evaluates to the same value for all inputs.)

You may assume that the three input values are nonnegative integers.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

For a harder challenge, check out ["The TAK function"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269557/the-tak-function).

### Test cases

```
(x, y, z) -> output

(10, 20, 100) -> 20
(20, 20, 100) -> 20
(20, 10, 100) -> 100
(20, 10, 10) -> 10
(20, 10, 0) -> 20
```

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 25 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,y,z)=>x>y?f(y,z,x):y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiEtulpSVpuhY702w1KnQqdao0be0q7Crt0zSAbJ0KTatKiPzNncn5ecX5Oal6OfnpGiUahgY6CkZAbGhgoKmpoK-voGsH5HOhKjIiVpEhmiIgG6cqoCK4KhyKwGrg9kE8sGABhAYA)

Not shortest but fun

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
(x,y,z)=>x>y?y>z?x:z:y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiEtulpSVpuhbbNCp0KnWqNG3tKuwq7SvtquwrrKqsKiGSN3cm5-cV5-ek6uXkp2uUaBga6CgYAbGhgYGmpoK-voKuHZDPharIiFhFhmiKgGycqoCK4KpwKAKrgdsH8cCCBRAaAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 31 bytes

```python
lambda x,y,z:x*(x>y>(y:=z))or y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhb7cxJzk1ISFSp0KnWqrCq0NCrsKu00Kq1sqzQ184sUKiGqbrYUFGXmlWikaRga6CgYAbGhgYGmpjKQyQWTMUKWUcCQMkSSAtJY5KBSGDJw4yBuWbAAQgMA)

Comment: Every day I learn new ways how not to write an if-then-else in python! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes

```hs
(x#y)z|x>y=(y#z)x|1<2=y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc6xCsMgGATg3ac4cFGwRZ1r3qBPYB0cAg1NQqgO/y95dxtKx5KDW77l7pnLa5zn3hVJ1m2ngYNi2TTt7uYD9zqWWhAQEZ018EedtUngF4PoT9yd@l@2CUmIJU/rMbvk7Q61vae14opHJMOmJVwGKKlBYDSN78f@AQ)

I see that [I4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323) found this approach before I did. Could've saved me the dozen minutes I spent trying to find a non-obvious approach. :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 12 bytes

```
⊡◿3+1⊗1≤↻1..
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4oqh4pe_Mysx4oqXMeKJpOKGuzEuLgoKZiBbMTAgMjAgMTAwXQpmIFsyMCAyMCAxMDBdCmYgWzIwIDEwIDEwMF0KZiBbMjAgMTAgMTBdCmYgWzIwIDEwIDBdCg==)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

*-1 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)*

```
f(a,b,c)=\{a<=b:b,b>c:a,c\}
```

Literally just the piecewise function given in the challenge description.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j0saxcxswf)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dbsooczaa0)

Comment: Doesn't `b>c:a,c` work?

Comment: @Neil oh yea, i was just copying the formula verbatim LOL

Answer (score 2):

## [Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 25 bytes

```
1,$0=$1>$2?$2>$3?$1:$3:$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fUEfFwFbF0E7FyF7FyE7F2F7F0ErF2ErFCChloGBkoGBoYMBlhMwyRGVBGQYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 30 bytes

```r
t=\(x,y,z)`if`(x>y,t(y,z,x),y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhb7SmxjNCp0KnWqNBMy0xI0KuwqdUo0gFydCk2dSk2IopvZaRqGBjoKRkBsaGCgqaygawfkcKVpGOEUNUQWBTJQhGGiSIJw_RArFyyA0AA)

Port of [@l4m2's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269686/55372)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 33 bytes

```r
\(x,y,z)`if`(x>y,`if`(y>z,x,z),y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3FWM0KnQqdao0EzLTEjQq7Cp1wIxKuyqdCqCoTqUmVGF2moahgY6CERAbGhhoKivo2gE5XGkaRjhFDZFFgQwUYZgokiBcP8TKBQsgNAA)

Straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Rü@2β3Bè
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6PAeB6Nzm4ydDq/4/z/a0EDHyEDH0MAgFgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W90eK7x4cWHVpdV2ispPGqbpKBkX@nyP@jwHgejc5uMnQ6v@K/zPzra0EDHyEDH0MAgVifaCJVtiM6GM0EsiEaD2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
R         # Reverse the (implicit) input-triplet
 ü        # For each overlapping pair:
  @       #  Do a ≥ check
          # (so we now have a pair [z≥y,y≥x])
   2β     # Convert this pair from a base-2 list to a base-10 integer
     3B   # Convert this base-10 integer to a base-3 integer
       è  # Use that to 0-based modular index into the (implicit) input-triplet
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

| input | `R` | `ü@` | `2β` | `3B` | (0-based modular index) | `è` (output) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `[10,20,100]` | `[100,20,10]` | `[1,1]` | `3` | `10` | `1` | `20` |
| `[20,20,100]` | `[100,20,20]` | `[1,1]` | `3` | `10` | `1` | `20` |
| `[20,10,100]` | `[100,10,20]` | `[1,0]` | `2` | `2` | `2` | `100` |
| `[20,10,10]` | `[10,10,20]` | `[1,0]` | `2` | `2` | `2` | `10` |
| `[20,10,0]` | `[0,10,20]` | `[0,0]` | `0` | `0` | `0` | `20` |
| `[10,20,0]` | `[0,20,10]` | `[0,1]` | `1` | `1` | `1` | `20` |

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mfeature+signatures`, 35 bytes

```perl
sub($x,$y,$z){$y<$x?$z<$y?$x:$z:$y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NElDpUJHpVJHpUqzWqXSRqXCXqXKRqXSXqXCSqXKSqWy9r@1SrytmkqahoOb5n9DAwUjAwVDAwMuI2SWISoLyjD4l19QkpmfV/xf1zctNbGktChVuzgzPQ/MAgoW5CQCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 40 bytes

```cpp
=IFS(A1<=A2,A2,(A1>A2)*(A2<=A3),A1,1,A3)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 27 bytes

```
t(x,y,z)=if(x>y,t(y,z,x),y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWu0s0KnQqdao0bTPTNCrsKnVKNIA8nQpNnUpNiIqb-YkFBTmVGokKunYKBUWZeSVAphKIo6QAZEYbxuooJEYbgUnjWE1NHYXoaEMDHSMDHUMDA6BotBEaxxCDg2AbxMZCrYU5EAA)

A port of [@l4m2's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269686/9288).

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 27 bytes

```
t(x,y,z)=if(x<=y,y,y>z,x,z)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWu0s0KnQqdao0bTPTNCpsbCuBnEq7Kp0KoBBExc38xIKCnEqNRAVdO4WCosy8EiBTCcRRUgAyow1jdRQSo43ApHGspqaOQnS0oYGOkYGOoYEBUDTaCI1jiMFBsA1iY6HWwhwIAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
.+
$*
^(1*¶)??(1*)¶\2
$2
\G1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZwQ46L9X0@bS0WLK07DUOvQNk17eyCteWhbjBGXihFXjLvh//@GBjoKRkBsaGDAZYTGNsRgw5kGAA) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on non-digits for convenience. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^(1*¶)??(1*)¶\2
$2
```

If `x<=y` then delete `x`, otherwise if `y<=z` then delete both `x` and `y`. (The `??` is needed to prefer the `x<=y` test.)

```
\G1
```

Convert the first remaining input to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
>Ɲi0‘ị
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list, `[x, y, z]`, and yields the result of the TAK function.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/u2NxMg0cNMx7u7v5/uP1R05r//6M1DA10FIyA2NDAQFOHS0HDCAvfECsfhQvixQIA)**

#### How?

```
>Ɲi0‘ị - Link: list of comparables, [x, y, z]
 Ɲ     - for neighbouring pairs:
>      -   greater than?         -> [x>y, y>z] == [not(x<=y), not(y<=z)]
  i0   - first 1-indexed index of 0, or 0 if not found
          -> 1 if x<=y
             2 if x>y and y<=z
             0 if x>y and y>z
    ‘  - increment
          -> 2 if x<=y
             3 if x>y and y<=z
             1 if x>y and y>z
     ị - 1-index into {[x, y, z]}
          -> y if x<=y
             z if x>y and y<=z
             x if x>y and y>z
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 25 bytes

```
Ans(2+(Ans(1)>Ans(2))cos(π(Ans(2)≠min(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans` as a list.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 28 bytes

```javascript
(x,y,z)=>x<=y?y:x>y&y<=z?z:x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGiEtulpSVpuhZ7NCp0KnWqNG3tKmxsK-0rrSrsKtUqbWyr7KusKiBKbu5Mzs8rzs9J1cvJT9co0TA00FEwAmJDAwNNTQV9fQVdOyCfC1WREbGKDNEUAdk4VQEVwVXhUARWA7cP4oEFCyA0AA)

Literal translation of the simple version.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>35</s></sup> 32 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)

```python
lambda x,y,z:[y,[z,x][y>z]][x>y]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY07DoMwDIZnOIU3kiogYKqQykUoQypAjQQhIqEiXKULC70Tt6kpVGXpYFn-_D-eL2XNvZXTXMEFrnNvKv-8QM2bW8FhYJaNSWZZNrIhz2w65nk2pDbfdVo0qu0MaKvdqu2gFrIEIdc70KYQMnEdIRWDclAY33BFygev2UeIik4oQgOtamGIB34KHqWu0_YGxRU5oRVP1QlpCCYwwA_dqqeFkyhkEONEYUhXcxy6JP7DogPDfYQ7-6Gvc2t6Aw)

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 36 bytes

Port of [l4m2's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269686/91267)

```python
f=lambda x,y,z:f(y,z,x)if x>y else y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY1BDoIwEEXXcIpZmNCaSoCVIcG71NjGSUppaDHUq7hho3fyNg6C0Y2Lmcl_8__M7eFiOHd2mu5D0Lv9c6MbI9vjScIoorjWmlEXI0cN4yGCMl5BXL0eW9f1AXz0qe56MGgVoJ117sMJbZ0maJ0ANTpooJWOqYs04m0kR4-O8dw7g4FlsDtAxnmadEMgs2ZbipJ0PdrA6IIA2vDl9fSUrCwEVFRlUfA5XBUpq_6w8ofR_IUr-6JPcvn0Ag)

Comment: The first answer needs the leading `f=` because it is a recursive function.

Comment: Python, 32 bytes: [`lambda x,y,z:[y,[z,x][y>z]][x>y]`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY07DoMwDIZnOIU3kiogYKqQykUoQypAjQQhIqEiXKULC70Tt6kpVGXpYFn-_D-eL2XNvZXTXMEFrnNvKv-8QM2bW8FhYJaNSWZZNrIhz2w65nk2pDbfdVo0qu0MaKvdqu2gFrIEIdc70KYQMnEdIRWDclAY33BFygev2UeIik4oQgOtamGIB34KHqWu0_YGxRU5oRVP1QlpCCYwwA_dqqeFkyhkEONEYUhXcxy6JP7DogPDfYQ7-6Gvc2t6Aw)

Comment: @Bubbler, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Funge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 29 bytes

```
"HTRF"4(&&&RROO`!2j@._2P`j$.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X8ggJclMy0VBTUwsK8vdPUDTKctCLNwpIyFLRc/j/39BAwchAwdDAgAsA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζＩ⎇‹ηθ⎇‹ζηθζη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oLmZ@Bxq8C8gOKMvNKNJwTi0s0QlKL8hKLKjV8UouLNTJ0FAo1dRRQxKp0FDKAYoU6ClWaIKampvX//4YKBgpG/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Straightforward approach. For a more interesting approach, my answer to the linked question needs to perform this calculation three times in a loop so it uses array indexing arithmetic.

```
Ｎθ                  First input as a number
  Ｎη                Second input as a number
    Ｎζ              Third input as a number
         η          Second input
        ‹           Is less than
          θ         First input
       ⎇            If true then
             ζ      Third input
            ‹       Is less than
              η     Second input
           ⎇        If true then
               θ    First input
                ζ   Else third input
                 η  Else second input
      Ｉ             Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 26 bytes

```c
f(x,y,z){x=x>y?y>z?x:z:y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRa4MwEMff@ykOoRDbyNqOPaxZ7cPYp5g@SEw62abFCEsifvVlURNXpYE79H7/uwv/0OhCqTEcSaywDlt5krE6q1if5VEfFelMUTbwnRUlCqFdgT19oWGike8pnKDd7zAcZtGRmU6NOs/3Uyx02s8b4H/CcKtk8spow/LlUCedttOqFA3Qj6ze2MzoJ6vHliCRb4dEPr/aeAow3P4/Bq6bVzWgfl1R5kzath1xny8gCs0qjvxFQnjwpc1UI7DdDnpvmr9@P2s0b8ApmVHlqLpLtaP6LhWW9s8ICoMO54xZNhm3bL7WVsJRsM4xjAFR3Oe1SEprkBuJQeDJSbvMTkzdmm7VmV/Kv7KLMNHPHw)